# Looping over levels of a variable then using egen command

Tags: loops, foreach, stata

I want to create a new variable that counts all the occurrences of a specified drug code over `27` columns. However, I want to do this for all drug codes that I have available. I am using a loop and the `egen` function `anycount()`.

However, when I have tried to run it I get the error:

> invalid name
>   r(198);

Below you can find an example of my data:

```
clear
input DrugList Drug1 Drug2 Drug3 Drug4 Drug5
1234 7934 1234 . . .
5678 1234 5678 . . .
9876 9876 3456 . . .
3456 9876 . . . .
7934 9876 5678 7934 1234 .
17453 5678 . . . .
end
```

The code I am using is the following:

```
levelsof DrugList

foreach drug in `r(levels)'{
    egen d_`drug' = anycount(Drug1-Drug27), values(`drug')
}
```

The output I expect is this:

```
  +------------------------------------------------------+
  | d_1234   d_3456   d_5678   d_7934   d_9876   d_17453 |
  |------------------------------------------------------|
  |      1        0        0        1        0         0 |
  |      1        0        1        0        0         0 |
  |      0        1        0        0        1         0 |
  |      0        0        0        0        1         0 |
  |      1        0        1        1        1         0 |
  |      0        0        1        0        0         0 |
  +------------------------------------------------------+
```

If I run the code without a loop for a specific code then everything works:

```
egen d_1234 = anycount(Drug1-Drug27), values(1234)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in your original data, you have drug codes in `DrugList` that contain decimals, negative values or even both. Stata does not consider these legal for variable names.

Consider the following toy example based on a slightly modified version of the data in your question:

```
clear
input DrugList Drug1 Drug2 Drug3 Drug4 Drug5
1234 7934 1234 . . .
5678 1234 5678 . . .
9876 9876 3456 . . .
3456.46 9876 . . . .
7934 9876 5678 7934 1234 .
17453 5678 . . . .
end

levelsof DrugList, clean

foreach drug in `r(levels)' {
    egen d_`drug' = anycount(Drug1-Drug5), values(`drug')
}
d_3456.4599609375 invalid name
r(198);
```

A solution that does not require removing the offending observations is to use the `floor()` function:

```
clear
input DrugList Drug1 Drug2 Drug3 Drug4 Drug5
1234 7934 1234 . . .
5678 1234 5678 . . .
9876 9876 3456 . . .
3456.46 9876 . . . .
7934 9876 5678 7934 1234 .
17453 5678 . . . .
end

levelsof DrugList, clean

foreach drug in `r(levels)' {
    local drug = floor(`drug')
    egen d_`drug' = anycount(Drug1-Drug5), values(`drug')
}
```

If you have negative values in `DrugList` you can use the `abs()` function instead:

```
clear
input DrugList Drug1 Drug2 Drug3 Drug4 Drug5
1234 7934 1234 . . .
5678 1234 5678 . . .
9876 9876 3456 . . .
-3456 9876 . . . .
7934 9876 5678 7934 1234 .
17453 5678 . . . .
end

levelsof DrugList, clean

foreach drug in `r(levels)' {
    local drug = abs(`drug')
    egen d_`drug' = anycount(Drug1-Drug5), values(`drug')
}
```

Of course, you can also combine the aforementioned functions:

```
clear
input DrugList Drug1 Drug2 Drug3 Drug4 Drug5
1234 7934 1234 . . .
5678 1234 5678 . . .
9876 9876 3456 . . .
-3456.46 9876 . . . .
7934 9876 5678 7934 1234 .
17453 5678 . . . .
end

levelsof DrugList, clean

foreach drug in `r(levels)' {
    local drug = abs(floor(`drug'))
    egen d_`drug' = anycount(Drug1-Drug5), values(`drug')
}
```

The results in all cases are those expected:

```
list, separator(0)

     +------------------------------------------------------+
     | d_3456   d_1234   d_5678   d_7934   d_9876   d_17453 |
     |------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |      0        1        0        1        0         0 |
  2. |      0        1        1        0        0         0 |
  3. |      1        0        0        0        1         0 |
  4. |      0        0        0        0        1         0 |
  5. |      0        1        1        1        1         0 |
  6. |      0        0        1        0        0         0 |
     +------------------------------------------------------+
```